# How to copy or move files -n levels up on OSX via shell

Tags: macos, zsh, find, mv, oh-my-zsh

How can I find all files of **certain type/name** and copy them **-n levels up**? Here is the filesystem tree structure:

```
germany/
       |
       adventure/
                |
                300x600/
                |      |
                |      file1.jpg
                |      file2.zip
                |
                400x600/
                       |
                       file8.jpg
                       file4.zip
switzerland/
           |
           adventure/...
```

There are many country folders, about 20 and the .zip files are not guaranteed to be 3 levels deep. I am currently in their parent folder, `countries/` and I wish to find and copy all **.zip** files up **one** level, to the `adventure/` directory of the appropriate country/ folder.

I tried:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec mv {}/.. \;
```

but that one failed miserably. It moved each file up one level, then these were moved yet again up one level.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I played a bit with solutions from the replies and read a lot of `man` pages :). Finally I accepted the solution which I liked the most as it is elegant and shell-independant.

Something I'm still trying to figure out:

1. Does `find` work as a loop or do curly brackets get treated as a "list/array" in other programming languages? *Meaning: does it get filled with the found results (i.e. strings) all at once and THEN passed to the command under `-exec`?*
2. Why did the move first happen one level up, then again one level up?
3. Is there a way to immediately tell `mv/cp` to go -n levels [up/down]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it shell-independent and condense it into one `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec \
sh -c 'echo cp -- "$0" "$(dirname "$0")"/..' {} \;
```

Remove the `echo` when you are sure that it does what you want.

Use `find` to locate the files. Execute a shell with `-exec sh -c`, passing the found file with `{}` as the first argument to that shell. The shell will therefore have the file path available as `$0`.

You can then use `dirname "$0"` and a [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) (`$(…)`) to get the parent directory of the file. Append as many `/..` as you want to traverse higher.

Note that I [quoted](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) the file names to prevent files with newlines or spaces in their name from being improperly expanded.

Comment: Side note: In your  question, you say you want to “copy”, but later on, you use the `mv` command. I assumed you wanted to copy files, as the title and the introduction say.

Comment: Got it! `mv`or `cp` doesn't matter, I can use and handle both :). So, `find` finds the paths to .zip files, fills the `{}` "object" with results. `-exec` executes `sh -c` with "read from string" option (-c) which "defines"(?) two arguments - first arg will be first `path/to/file.zip` from the results `{}`. Then, extract-parent-dir-of-the-file, finally go up one level and `cp` file. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what's going on here! The `sh` call has two argumentsoptions in this case, one is `-c "cmd"` (= “take the commands to be executed from the string that follows”), and the second one is `{}`, which is – as you correctly say – the path to the first found file, then in the second loop the second file, etc. This `-exec sh -c "…"` approach is pretty useful for more complex `find` scripts that you'd otherwise have to write a few loops for.

Comment: Could you elaborate just a bit more - I'm confused about the string. There is a command (cp) and following it are two variables ($0 and $(...)). How does this internally work? How does full path/to/file end up in $0 and than to that is applied another command dirname? Vielen dank!

Comment: `$0` is the first argument passed to `sh -c '…'`. You can run `sh -c 'echo $0 $1 $2' foo bar baz`  and you'd get `foo bar baz` as output. In your case the first argument was `{}` which `find` replaces with the path to the found file. So the first argument to `cp` ends up being the path to the file. The second argument needs to be the parent folder of the file, so we need to get the folder name first …

Comment: To do that, the command `dirname "$0"` is executed. Its output is – obviously – just the directory of the file. The output of the command is literally put where the second argument to `cp` goes – that's called command substitution (see the link above). Command substitution is done *before* the rest of the line is evaluated. It's very useful if you want to have your shell command contain the output of another command. So `$(dirname "$0")` ends up being `/path/to/folder` in the final command, to which we just append `/..` in order to get the parent folder.

Comment: Got it! It's just that the syntax seems weird to me. Find, then options, then sh, then argument to sh and in the end again something that "works with" find (curly braces). I guess that's just sth. to memorise ;)

Answer (score 0):

tried it with ubuntu zsh 5.0.2:

```
for pdir in */
do
  cd $pdir
  for dir in */
  do
    cd $dir
    mv */*.zip .
    cd ..
  done
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: Close. I want to have all the .zip files two levels up, meaning in the `adventure/` subdirectory of the `germany/` directory. Also, there are other directories named per country names so Id like to be able to issue a command for all these (like Austria/, Germany/, ...). Thanks

Comment: ok - let me try again - but again, no zsh to validate it ;-)

Comment: I tried this within a ubuntu lxc container and with zsh 5.0.2. Should work like a charm ;-)

Comment: This should work, but only for one directory at the root level (e.g. `germany`), not all of them.

Comment: how about now? :-D

Answer (score 0):

Just the quick alternative if the reality is that simple as given example:

```
cd germany
mv */*/*.zip .
```

(and there are not zillion of files)

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, the OP wants to do that for *every* folder, not just `germany`. So you'd need a loop over all folders.

Comment: Yes, I need to do that for all the "country" folders, not just one and I am not certain that the .zip files will always be three levels deep. Thanks anyway ;)